# How to fix the problem for the color schemes differences for the mac and windows screens

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, color, sketch-app, interface-design

I am a product designer, I use MacBook Pro for my design work. Whenever I design an app/website/web pages after it went live the big problems comes up as color differences in the Apple screen and other windows/Linus etc screens. So how should I resolve this? Is there any method/codes libraries available for this to use or if there any method available to use while at the time of designing the screens.

Thanks in the advance.

Comment: Unless people have calibrated monitors (which they do not) theres nothing you can do. Consider that you are obsessing about color, but when did you last hardware calibrate your monitors? You should be do this biweekly.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing monitors man is like comparing cars, they all have 4 wheels, but the rest is all very different. No real fix, so better move on.

Answer (score 1):

The only method that will work to some degree, is to make sure raster images for the web are saved with an sRGB colour profile - which is the worldwide standard for colour reproduction on the web.

However, even if you have calibrated your own screen/devices, you can't calibrate colours on other users' screens/devices so they will look exactly the same as your device. It's not possible, there are too many different manufacturers and user settings.